# Default way of showing windows explorer search in windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-10-v1703

Whenever I open a folder in windows 10 and enter something in the search field, the results appear in the "Content" way of viewing them. I want them to be viewed in the "list" or "details" way.

How to change the default?

Comment: When you search in explorer you can see a search option in tittle of explorer. Click on it and uncheck file contents.

Comment: @Biswa I did many times, thats why I want it default.. It doesn't stay there

Comment: Change the dword registry value `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Search\PrimaryProperties\UnindexedLocations\SearchOnly` to **1** to turn of contents.